# Filter from array within array in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my array:

```
places = [
    {
        "long_name": "Sydney",
        "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Perth",
        "types": [
            "administrative",
            "political"
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I want to filter this array with the **types** of administrative so that I get the result as Perth.

I am doing this which completely seems wrong.

var city = places.filter(x => x.types === "administrative");

Comment: this is actually address_components from google place api.

Comment: Replace triple equals with includes to check if string is included in types array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const places = [
    {
        "long_name": "Sydney",
        "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Perth",
        "types": [
            "administrative",
            "political"
        ]
    }
]

const filteredByTypes = places.filter(e => e.types.includes('administrative'))

console.info(filteredByTypes)
```

You need to use `includes` array method.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the `types` array includes `"administrative"`:

```js
places.filter(place => place.types.includes("administrative"))
```